# 'Media File Selector' blank screen

Tags: files, media

To use already existing image, I choose 'Media File Selector' Widget.
But, it gives me blank page like this when I click on 'Library' to choose already existing image in Drupal-7.

[image: Media Library]

***Version of the Media:***
1) Media: YouTube
(media_youtube) 7.x-2.0-rc4

2) Media
(media) 7.x-1.4

In Media browser settings, Allowed file extensions are 
(jpg jpeg gif png txt doc docx xls xlsx pdf ppt pptx pps ppsx odt ods odp mp3 mov m4v mp4 mpeg avi ogg oga ogv wmv ico)

Thanks!

Comment: Hello. It looks like a bugreport, and "issues found in existing modules" are listed as something you shouldn't ask here. Are you trying to debug & fix it by yourself? If so, what have you tried so far? And have you seen [this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/7560/16495)? Got any results with methods posted there?

Comment: I am new to Drupal and I tried to search for the same question while I found this question here - http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/107809/upload-images-tab-blank-when-adding-media 
But, I couldn't find answer so posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether to making 'jQuery' version down to some level is good or not. But, I tried to downgrade the jquery version to 1.5 and it works well with my website.

I refereed this post:
[Media 7.x-1 Library tab empty](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/120054/media-7-x-1-library-tab-empty?rq=1)

Now, I can see all my images by selecting 'jQuery' version - 1.5.

To do so:
Go to 
Home » Administration » Configuration » Development

[image: jQuery Update]

Thanks!

Vidushi

Comment: Yes this also worked for me.